# Advanced splitting of search term with regex, respecting rules for hyphens and dots when part of words

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex

I did some research but I could not find the solution to a problem which I assume to be very common:

I want to split the search terms, supporting quotation marks and in a smart way handle dots and hyphens.

I could write a long list of requirements, but I think the following example which contains all problematic aspects is more simple and clear:

```
My test, one. two ASP.net 030-333-12345 end
```

Should split to:

```
My
test
one
two
ASP.net
030-333-12345 
end
```

I could achieve this with some substitutes and re-substitute after the splitting but I guess a pro in **regex** would solve this more efficient and elegant in one step.

I came to this but this does not handle the . and - correctly.

```
var words = Regex
    .Matches(keywords, @"(?<match>\w+)|\""(?<match>[\w\s]*)""")
    .Cast<Match>()
    .Select(m => m.Groups["match"].Value)
    .ToList();
```

The result is wrong, as it gives:

```
My
test
one
two
ASP
net
030
333
12345 
end
```

The problematic part is the \w, I think, because its definition of a word does not match my requirement.

Comment: Try `\w+(?:\S+\w+)*`. Live demo https://regex101.com/r/ESzu53/1

Comment: Another idea: [`\S+\b`](https://regex101.com/r/sygMc8/1) (depends on requirements).

Comment: I'd be a bit more cautious. The question only mentions dots and hyphens thus I'd suggest `@"(?<match>\w+(?:[-.]\w+)*)|""(?<match>\w+(?:(?:\s+|[.-])\w+)*)"""`. Tillito, does it work for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to match word characters and any non-word characters if they are followed by at least one word character:

```
\w+(?:\S+\w+)*
```

[Live demo](https://regex101.com/r/ESzu53/1)

Note: if you only want to include `-` and `.` then replace `\S` with `[.-]`:

```
\w+(?:[.-]+\w+)*
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks a lot!